# How to open .xlt file in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .XLT file which i want to read/write in .net. Can it be opened using .net framework ?    As far as i know XLT is Excel Template I have an .XLT file which is like a registration form wherein i want to fill the cells from .net .Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several options:

- use [OpenXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx) from MS
- use a 3rd-party library with several additonal functionalities like creating PDFs etc. (examples are [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) or [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) or [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp)...)